# How can I apply a conditional effect to a button based on value in the ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, button, effects, dropshadoweffect

I can easily add a little glow effect to a button using something like this:

```
<Button ...>
  <Button.Effect>
    <DropShadowEffect ... />
  </Button.Effect>
</Button>
```

How can I apply the effect conditionally, based on a value in the ViewModel?

Basically I want the button to "glow" if a new document has been added in the last few days.  I can supply the bool value indicating if the glow is required as a property of the ViewModel.

I was thinking of just creating two buttons attached to the same command, hiding one and showing the other based on the ViewModel.  That would work, but it seems a bit brute forced.

Thoughts?

Thanks.

J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a style for your Button with a [`DataTrigger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
<Button Content="Hello" Command="{Binding HelloCommand}">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeCondition}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Effect">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DropShadowEffect />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Note that `SomeCondition` is a boolean property in your view model. Only when `SomeCondition` is `true`, the effect gets applied.

Comment: Ah...  Yes, of course!  For some reason I wasn't thinking about `Effect` as just a settable property...  Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help. If this answer solves your problem, please [mark it as the accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you really need a `DataTrigger` Like Below,

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PropertyFromViewModel}" Value="True">
      <Setter .../>
      <Setter .../>
   </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

*Example*

```
    <Button Content="Hello" Command={Binding YourCommand}>
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Glow}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect Color="Blue"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Without the "<Setter.Value>", you'll get a System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException.